# Как сделать слайдер с меняющейся картинкой и полосой прокрутки текста?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Добрый день! Нужно сверстать вот такой вот слайдер - [image: слайдер]

Я и в верстке новичок и js пользуюсь только на уровне подключения плагинов JQuery, и у меня возник вопрос как сделать такой слайдер? 
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на стрелки менялась фоновая картинка и перемещался текст, который в активном состоянии становился бы оранжевым.
Интересует и как правильно разметить такой слайдер и скрипт. Может быть вы знаете сайты с такими слайдерами? Или готовые плагины, которые умеют так делать (я ничего толкового не нашла)?
Буду рада любой помощи, спасибо!

UPD: Через OwlCarusel сделала прокрутку картинки и стилизовала стрелки, но по-прежнему не понимаю как к этому добавить полосу с текстом..

Comment: Вы хотите именно плагин подключить или свой написать на jquery?

Comment: Если есть плагины с возможностью сделать такой слайдер, то проще для меня будет подключить плагин. Потому что сама-то я точно не напишу скрипт)

Comment: думаю Sly http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html подойдет.
Сам в поисках, т.к Sly показывает список изображений и ползунок, НО не выделяет текущий слайд (мне требуется с увеличением).

Answer (score 1):

Один из лучших готовых слайдеров это наверное [Layerslider](http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/). Он может буквально все. Также отличный и стабильный слайдер [OwlSlider](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/).

Взгляните на них.

Comment: Вот OwlCarusel пользуюсь обычно, да, хороший слайдер, но вроде как там нет возможности сделать вот такой слайдер как нужен(